# How to find a 7 letter word without the letter s and contains only one vowel in a word file?

Tags: python, file-search

I am being asked to program a code that will print words from "dictionary.txt" (a 250,000 word file) that contain only one vowel, no letter "s" and is 7 letters long. I know I will have to define a function that opens the file and searches it for those requirements.

**I am not allowed to use regex, and the file is one word per line.**

Here's my current python script:

```
a="a"
e="e"
i="i"
o="o"
u="u"
y="y"



def search():    
    Input=open("dictionary.txt","r") 
    for word in Input:
        word=Input.lower()
        vowel=len(word-a)==6 or len(word-e)==6 or len(word-i)==6 or len(word-o)==6 or len(word-u)==6 or len(word-y)==6
        if len(word)==7 and "s" not in word and vowel==True:
            return word

 print(search())
```

Comment: Could you tell us how dictionary.txt is formatted, please?

Comment: That's not a valid Python code!

Comment: Are you allowed to use regex ? Because prepare for a very heavy one!

Comment: Assuming that dictionary.txt is formatted one word per line:  `with Input = open("dictionary.txt") : for line in Input:`.  You then need to remember that `line` will have a trailing newline (so ignore unless len is *8*, and ignore if `'s' in line`

Comment: edited my answer because you said you cant use `regex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for regex. Sets are quite fast.

```
text = open('dictionary.txt').read()

vowels = 'aeiou'
vowelsSet = set(vowels)

for word in text.split():
    word = word.lower()
    if len(word)==7 and not 's' in word and len(set(word)-vowelsSet)==6:
        print (word)
```

The open-read combinatio in the first line slurps up the collection of words — assuming that it contains no punctuation other than apostrophes within words and no more than a single line.

By comparing the size of the **set** of characters in any given word with the size of the **set** of vowels it is possible to determine whether a vowel has been repeated. The principle is that, for instance, the size of the set of characters in *moan* is 4, that of the set of characters in *moon* is 3.

Comment: what do i set text equal to?

Answer (score 2):

One liner regex, for the challenge :

```
^(?:[b-df-hj-np-rtv-z])*[aeiou](?:[b-df-hj-np-rtv-z])*(?<=\w{7})$
```

- `(?:[b-df-hj-np-rtv-z])*` non capturing 0 to many consonents except s
- `[aeiou]` exactly one vowel
- `(?:[b-df-hj-np-rtv-z])*` non capturing 0 to many consonents except s

You now have the rule "exactly one vowel"

- `(?<=\w{7})`from this point go back to the beginning and see if this matches : exactly 7 letters

Of course I agree three simple tests could be done for better maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dictionary.txt just contains space separated words and linebreaks, this could be done in this manner:

```
# Open the file and construct a list of single words
with open("dictionary.txt", "r") as infile:
    x = [i.strip() for i in infile.read().split(" ")]

# Function for finding number of vowels in a word
def vowels(word):
    count = 0
    for i in word:
        if i in 'aeoui':
            count += 1
    return count

# Check the length of each word, if it contains s and if the number of vowels is one at most
for i in x:
    if len(i) == 7 and "s" not in i and vowels(i) <= 1:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be the easiest and simplest way to achieve your task, by using a regex.

```
 with open("dictionary.txt","r") as file: #use r to open in read only mode to not mess with file
    words=[]
    for line in file: #loop through every line to get all words
        words.append(line)
import re

for word in words:
    if len(re.findall('[aeiou]', word)) == 1 and len(word)==7 and "s" not in word: #checks if there is only one vowel and length is 7
        print(word)
```

**EDIT:**
Because you have edited to say you are not allowed to use a regex you can do this.

```
with open("dictionary.txt","r") as file: 
        words=[]
        for line in file: #loop through every line to get all words
            words.append(line)

for word in words:
    if sum(letter in "aeiou" for letter in word)==1 and "s" not in word and len(word)==7:
        print(word)
```

Comment: You must also check for unexisting "s" but the idea is there.

Comment: Why store the dictionary? (Rather than process on the fly).  Also you appear to match words that are *at least* 7 characters.  The question calls for *exactly* 7.

Comment: I also think using regular expressions is overkill here:  `sum([(letter in 'aeiou') for letter in word])` will return the same value.

Comment: didnt see the doesnt contain `s` or exactly 7 thought it was more than 7 fixed code now

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at the desk so I can't give you a codified answer, but my first instinct is to use a regex to select the words you're after. the "re" library is where you want to start.

https://pymotw.com/2/re/

they'll take a little getting used to but they're invaluable for sifting through strings.

If you're totally new to them, there are a lot of interactive tutorials like this one (https://regexone.com/) that can get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you read the whole dictionary file into an array and then loop through this array (with 'word' as loop variable), put this before the loop:

```
import re

# this to make sure there is no 's' in word and its length is exactly 7 characters
no_s_re = re.compile(r'^[a-rt-z]{7}$', re.IGNORECASE)

# this to count vowels (later)
vowels_re = re.compile(r'[aioue]', re.IGNORECASE)
```

and this is the loop body:

```
if no_s_re.match(word) and len(vowels_re.findall(word)) == 1:
     print word
```

Comment: You can do `[^s]` to say "anything but `s`" in regex